# Can I insert one variable into other variable in Xsl?

Tags: xslt

```
<xsl:variable name="id">
  <idNum>0607V45621014F</idNum>
</xsl:variable> 

<xsl:variable name="pathId" select="Orders/Order[ORD_Num='$id/idNum']"/>
```

....not select the idNum

an other..not..

```
<xsl:variable name="XmlFile" select="YG.xml"/>
<xsl:value-of select="document($XmlFile)/aziende/azienda/ragione_sociale"/>
```

or other...not..

```
<xsl:variable name="tagName" select="aziende"/>
<xsl:value-of select="document($XmlFile)/$tagName/azienda/ragione_sociale"/>
```

Comment: Please reformat your question. Writing stuff like "help me!", "thanks" etc. will repel people to answer. Use full sentences. Describe the desired input and output, like "I got variable x='ab',y='c', I want z='abc'". I can't make out a meaningful difference in the last two examples.

Answer (score 3):

1)

```
<xsl:variable name="pathId" select="Orders/Order[ORD_Num='$id/idNum']"/>
```

You are saying: An `Order` element wich has at least one `ORD_Num` child with string value equal to `'$id/idNum'`.

Replace with:

```
<xsl:variable name="pathId" select="Orders/Order[ORD_Num=$id]"/>
```

Because the string value of $id variable (a Result Tree Fragment as you define) is `0607V45621014F`.

**Note**: It would be better if you define $id as a string like `select="'0607V45621014F'"`. Also, you can't (in XSLT 1.0) do: `[ORD_Num=$id/idNum]` because `/` operator can't be apply to a RTF.

2)

```
<xsl:variable name="XmlFile" select="YG.xml"/>   
<xsl:value-of select="document($XmlFile)/aziende/azienda/ragione_sociale"/>
```

Here, you are saying: Let be $XmlFile a node set with all `YG.xml` elements childs of context node, etc.

Replace (if you want a document with relative uri `YG.xml`)

```
<xsl:variable name="XmlFile" select="'YG.xml'"/>
```

Note: this does not trought an error because `document()` is very versatile (It's the few ones that take an `object` as param)

3)

```
<xsl:variable name="tagName" select="aziende"/>                             
<xsl:value-of select="document($XmlFile)/$tagName/azienda/ragione_sociale"/>
```

This does not work because the right expresion of `/` must be a path (In XSLT 2.0 can be a function as well).

Replace with:

```
<xsl:variable name="tagName" select="document($XmlFile)/aziende"/>                             
<xsl:value-of select="$tagName/azienda/ragione_sociale"/>
```

Or

```
<xsl:variable name="tagName" select="'aziende'"/>                             
<xsl:value-of select="document($XmlFile)/*[name()=$tagName]/azienda/ragione_sociale"/>
```